# Specify an app to startup first in Mule EE

Tags: mule

I have one service manager app which all other apps on the current mule node use. I want this app to start up first before other apps.

Saw the documentation, http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Application+Deployment
which mentions the order will be preserved for apps mentioned in the command line, but in my case, I want to only specify Service Manager app, any other app in the apps folder should be picked up. Since the list of other apps is dynamic, I dont want to specify that.

Is there any way (hack), I can use for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option here would be to create a bash/bat script that generate the list of the other apps it got from an ls/dir command and then leverage the -app argumented you pointed out